# Get value of an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

I am fetching the data from CSV file using [Jquery CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv).
Below code returns an object

```
var check = $.get('../../../data/testers.csv');  //Fetches all the data and stores in variable
  console.log(Object.keys(check));               //Here it tries to get all the keys, so I know what to call to get the required data
  console.log(check);                            //Displays everything
```

This is the output of the code shown above:

[image: Output]

As we see my data is in responseText: How can I fetch the data?
I tried check.responseText, but it's not working. (As responseText is not the key, I am not supposed to get the value. Yet was just giving a try)

How to get the data (responseText)?

Comment: That confused me more @Satpal

Comment: `$.get('../../../data/testers.csv', function(data){ console.log(data) })`

Comment: That's great, now I will go though those answers, they will make more sense to me. Thank you!